# disassociate windows username from subclipse without saving credentials

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I am using subclipse with eclipse indigo on Windows 7. When I commit a change and am prompted for my username/password, the plugin pre-populates my svn username with my Windows username in the authentication dialog box. I'd like it to put my repository username instead (or alternately nothing), but I don't want to save my credentials. I can only find instructions for saving both username and password.

I don't have anything stored in C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple. I've tried saving my password and then modifying the file which gets put in svn.simple, but it's not clear to me how to edit it manually, and deleting the couple of lines which store the password does not work.

I've tried including my username in the path of my repository URL(https://svnuser@server/path/to/repo), checking out a project, and synchronizing with the repository. When I try to commit something, my Windows username is pre-populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit %APPDATA%\Subversion\config and in the [auth] section add:

store-passwords = no

Subversion will cache your username but not your password.

Note that in the %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers file you can also override the default username:

username = myusername

You can put this in the [global] section or in a custom group for a specific domain.